# ¿Como obtener un registro en linq en asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

hago la siguiente consulta con linq, pero no puedo obtener ese id que recupero en la consulta.

```
var seccionGrado = (from sg in _context.SeccionGrado
                                    where sg.IdSeccion == user.IdSeccion
                                    && sg.IdGrado == user.IdGrado
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        id = sg.IdSeccionGrado
                                    }).ToList();

var s = Convert.ToInt32(seccionGrado[0]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás intentando convertir un objeto anonimo a un int, intenta var s = seccionGrado[0].id;

Comment: ¿Te fue útil la respuesta publicada?

Answer (score 1):

Estás intentando convertir un objeto anónimo a entero.

Podes usar [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ni/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) o [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ni/library/bb342451(v=vs.110).aspx) para obtener un único elemento de la lista resultante de la consulta, ojo que este último método lanzará una excepción si hay más de un elemento que cumple el criterio. Ambos retornarán el valor por defecto según el tipo de dato resultante, que para el caso de un [int](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table) es 0.

Te dejo un ejemplo con este último método.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    class SeccionGrado {
        public int Id;

        public SeccionGrado(int Id) {
            this.Id = Id;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<SeccionGrado> grados = new List<SeccionGrado>();
        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
            grados.Add(new SeccionGrado(i));
        }

        int s = (from g in grados where g.Id == 3 select g.Id).SingleOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```